# How can I compact these sed commands into one?

Tags: sed

I do some replacements in an XML file (I know this is bad but it's only for quickly testing out some stuff - normally I would use a parser for this) using sed. I have 4 statements which look quite the same, i.e. the matching part differs only in the key

```
  sed -i "s/\(key=\"liferay.db.host\" value=\)\".*\"/\1\"$hostname\"/" "$installer_directory/silent.xml"
  sed -i "s/\(key=\"idm.backend.db.host\" value=\)\".*\"/\1\"$hostname\"/" "$installer_directory/silent.xml"
  sed -i "s/\(key=\"idm-frontend.portal-tarent.tarent-frontend-host\" value=\)\".*\"/\1\"$hostname\"/" "$installer_directory/silent.xml"
  sed -i "s/\(key=\"openid-idp.hostname\" value=\)\".*\"/\1\"$hostname\"/" "$installer_directory/silent.xml"
```

Now I wonder if there is some way to put these into one sed statement?

Something like

```
/\(key="(first_key|second_key|third_key)"\) value=\)\".*\"/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\(key="\(liferay\.db\.host\|idm\.backend\.db\.host\|idm-frontend\.portal-tarent\.tarent-frontend-host\|openid-idp\.hostname\)" value=\)".*"/\1"'"$hostname"'"/' "$installer_directory/silent.xml"
```

Used alternation to shorten the four commands to one and replaced periods, which may have be interpreted as metacharacters, to match real periods.